# dropdown menu to auto post when selected

Tags: php, javascript, html

How would I make a drop down menu post automatically when an option has been chosen?

```
<SELECT NAME="select_page"><?php echo $options1;?></SELECT>
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you read _anything_ before asking this question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can utilize the `onchange` event for the `select` element, and code a form submit:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option>blue</option>
        <option>red</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

That will automatically submit the form when the value is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that jQuery is referencing the `<select>` tag by its ID, so put one in the tag. Also, you can use AJAX to post your data if you wish to receive something back.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#Sel').change(function() {
                    var opt = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "receiving_file.php",
                        data: 'selected_opt=' + opt,
                        success:function(data){
                            alert('This was sent back: ' + data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<select id = "Sel">
    <option value ="Song1">default value<br>
    <option value ="Song2">Break on through<br>
    <option value ="Song3">Time<br>
    <option value ="Song4">Money<br>
    <option value ="Song5">Saucerful of Secrets
</select>
```